# Issue with POSTS when deploying MVC app to Azure App Service

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-web-app-service, razor-pages

I have a completed web app that runs perfectly fine on localhost. Every endpoint is hit correctly and goes off without a hitch. BUT, when I published this web app on to an Azure App Service, none of the POST calls are hit. When I observe what's happening inside of the network tab I see 404's. This appears to only be happening with POSTs and not GETs. GETs seem to be working fine.

Also, it is probably important to note that I am using Razor page handlers to trigger the actions. As you can see, I have a Razor page handler `asp-page-handler="Login"` that *should* be triggering an action in the code behind called `OnPostLogin`.

CSHTML:

```html
 <form class="text-center p-5" method="post">
     <h5>UserName</h5>
     <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="error-message"></div>
     <input type="text" id="defaultLoginFormEmail" class="form-control mb-4" placeholder="UserName" asp-for="@Model.UserName">
     <h5>Password</h5> 
     <input type="password" id="defaultLoginFormPassword" class="form-control mb-4" placeholder="Password" asp-for="@Model.Password">
     <button class="btn btn-block my-4" type="submit" asp-page-handler="Login">Sign in</button>
 </form>
```

Here is the code behind method for this Razor page:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostLogin()
 {
            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.UserName, Input.Password, false, false);
            // if successful login
            else if (result.Succeeded)
                Response.Redirect(Request.Path.ToString());

            // if unsuccessful
            else return RedirectToPage("/Account/LoginError");

            return Page();
}
```

It doesn't even appear to be getting hit when I click the login button. Bear in mind that this isn't just an issue with this specific POST. It is an issue with ALL of the POSTS (only on azure apps service, not on localhost).

Thank you in advance for your willingness to help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the delay everyone! I was home for the holidays.

So it turns out that the problem with the POSTs was that I forgot to grant the correct privileges to the Azure IP address that was attempting to make the posts to the database. It was running fine locally because I was using different databases with the correct privileges granted. Here is how I granted all the privileges to the specified user in case you are not familiar.

```sql
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON databaseName.* TO 'user'@'address';

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Worked just fine after that. Thanks everyone for the insight!

Answer (score 0):

I create a Razor Pages web app based on ASP.NET core.

**Razor page handler:**
[image]

**Controller code:**
[image]

It works without 404 after publish to Azure.

**Get:**
[image]

**Post:**
[image]

Comment: In order to determine the reason, could you please add the attribute and test locally? Please let me know if it works or not. @Andrew Smith

Comment: It already works locally without the `[HttpPost]`. When I do add this attribute I get a warning saying 'Cannot add attribute to Razor page handler method`.

Comment: I use the wrong project before, now it is same as yours. Unfortunately I didn't reproduce the error. could you please post the whole error detail? @AndrewSmith